# Special Characters eg. @ / Prevent Line Breaks from Working in Emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I am using the System.Net.Mail classes to send emails.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(AppConstants.SmptHostName);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppConstants.SmptUsername, AppConstants.SmptPassword);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(emailSettings.AdminEmailAddress, emailSettings.EmailSender);
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailSettings.ApplicationEmailAddress);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Body = GetApplicationEmail();
message.Subject = "New Application";
client.Send(message);
```

I am constructing the email to be imported by a different application in the format:

```
String.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", "FieldName", "FieldValue", Environment.NewLine);

private string GetApplicationEmail()
    {
            string messageContents = "";
            var fieldList = _fieldList;

            foreach (var field in fieldList)
            {
                messageContents += String.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", field.Name, field.Value, Environment.NewLine);
            }

            return messageContents;
     }
```

The email will look something like this:

```
Field1:Value1
Field2:Value2
Field3:Value3
```

My problem arises when special characters esp. such as a forward slash / or at symbol @ are in the values. Instead of each field:value combination being on separate lines, they are on 1 line. eg.

```
Field1:Value1
Field2:Value2
Field3:Different/Value Field4:Extra / LongValue Field5:PeanutsAreGood
Field6:Another Value
```

The email is being sent as "plain text". I can't encode the special characters nor can characters such as a forward slash be escaped.

My only current solution is to replace the characters with spaces, however this breaks functionality. Is there another solution?

Comment: With the code provided, there's no reason it would keep them on the same line. You might have something wrong in the `GetApplicationEmail` method.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - The GetApplicationEmail method simply loops through a list of database fields and for each one instead of "FieldName" & "FieldValue" - you could substitute field.Property. These are both string values.

Comment: Original post has been updated with a simplified version of the GetApplicationEmail method.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing there to indicate why it would be on the same line. There may be an issue with the way the field value is encoded. BTW, you could use a `StringBuilder` class instead of concatenating strings; it has an `AppendFormat()` method that takes the same parameters as `String.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

1 solution could be send the email in HTML format by using `message.IsBodyHtml = true`

Comment: I am unable to send HTML encoded emails in this case.

Comment: your code looks good to me, could you post the code for GetApplicationEmail() method ?

Comment: My code looks good to me too. That's why I have posted this question. ;-) I have updated my original post with a simplified version of the GetApplicationEmail method.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you do something like this?**

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
      client.EnableSsl = true;
      client.Port = 587;
      client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someEmail", "somePass");
      MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from", "Name");
      MailAddress to = new MailAddress("toEmail");
      MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

      string fieldName = @"$%^^TheField";
      string fieldValue = @"the test value)(/%";
      string string1 = String.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", fieldName, fieldValue, Environment.NewLine);

      string fieldName2 = @"anotheremail@mail.com/\";
      string fieldValue2 = @"\#the test value2";
      string string2 = String.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", fieldName2, fieldValue2, Environment.NewLine);

      List<string> messageBody = new List<string>();
      messageBody.Add(string1);
      messageBody.Add(string2);

      foreach (string str in messageBody)
      {
        message.Body += str;
      }

      message.Subject = "New Application";
      client.Send(message);

      //NonStaticClass cls = new NonStaticClass();
      //cls.GetVariable();
    }
```

Comment: I tried using a literal string like you suggested, but it made no difference.

Comment: Wow, that is strange, I just tested it and it worked fine. Are you using an exchange email server or private email server. I wonder if it does its own parsing/formatting?

Comment: In my testing environment, I am sending using one of the largest ISPs in my country. When I go live, I send using my own email server. This makes no difference. I should also mention that this was working when I originally constructed it 2 years ago. My customer got in contact with me this morning to report the new issue.

Comment: Well, you could debug this and make sure your message body is formatted correctly before the message is sent, and if it is, it is not your code, it has to be something else along the way.

Comment: Yes. That is the first thing that I tried and there was nothing that looked amiss.